# redirecting to index page recreating array-Session Lost

Tags: php, arrays, class, session, mysqli

Whenever I use browser back button to go back it is working good and storing the cart in session. But, when I go back using an anchor tag that redirects to index.php, the session is lost or a new array is made.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'connectiondb.php';

    class dbcook {


    public function Display_book()
    {

        $connect=new DBCONNECT();
        $link=$connect->DBCONNECTION();
        $disq_qry="select * from tbbook";
        $dis_result=mysqli_query($link,$disq_qry);
        $i=1;
        $output[]='<form name=abc action=index.php method=POST >';
        $output[]="<table border=5>";
        while($dis_row=mysqli_fetch_row($dis_result))
        {
            $i++;
            if($i==2)
            {
                $output[]='<tr>';
                $i=0;
            }
            $output[]="<td>";
            $output[]="<img src=$dis_row[5] width=50 />";
            $output[]="</td>";
            $output[]='<td>';
            $output[]="Title:<a href=details.php?bid=$dis_row[0] >$dis_row[1]</a><br>";
            $output[]="Author:$dis_row[2]<br>";
            $output[]="Publisher:$dis_row[3]<br>";
            $output[]="Price:$dis_row[4]";
            $output[]="<input type=checkbox name=add[] value=$dis_row[0] />";
            $output[]='</td>';
            if($i==1)
            {
                $output[]='</tr>';

            }
        }
        $output[]='<tr>';
        $output[]='<td>';
        $output[]='<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Add" />';
        $output[]='</td>';
        $output[]='</tr>';
        $output[]='</table>';
        $output[]='</form>';
        echo join($output);
        if(isset($_POST["btnsubmit"]))
        {
          //  session_start();
            $add=$_POST["add"];
            foreach ($add as $value )
            {
              // if(isset($bid))

                   // $_SESSION["bid"]=$value;

             $bid[]=$value; 

            }
          $_SESSION["bid"]=$bid;
           //print_r($_SESSION["bid"]);
         header('location: bookcart.php?action=Add');
        //  echo$_SESSION["bid"];
        }
        }
    public function Cart_Add()
    {
        $connect=new DBCONNECT();
        $connect->DBCONNECTION();
        if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
            $cart=$_SESSION["cart"];
        if(isset($_SESSION["bid"]))
            $bid=$_SESSION["bid"];
        if(isset($_REQUEST["action"]))
            $action=$_REQUEST["action"];
        switch ($action)
        {
            case 'Add':

                  if(isset($cart))
                {
                    $cart=$bid; 
                   //echo"if work";
                }
                else
                {
                    $cart=$bid;
                 //   echo"else work";
                }

                break;   
        }
          $_SESSION["cart"]=$cart;
             // print_r($_SESSION["cart"]);

    }
    public function Cart_detail()
    {
       // session_start();
        $connect=new DBCONNECT();
        $link=$connect->DBCONNECTION();
        $totalamt=0;

        if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
        {
            if($_SESSION["cart"]!="")
            {

               $arraybid=$_SESSION["cart"];
               $d= implode(",",$arraybid);
                $items= explode(',',$d);
              //  echo $bid;
              foreach ($items as $item)
              {
                  $contents[$item]= isset($contents[$item])?$contents[$item]+1:1;
              }
              $out[]="<form name=abc action=bookcart.php?action=Update method=POST>";
              $out[]='<table border=2>';
              $out[]='<tr><th></th><th>Book Detail</th><th>Publisher</th><th>Price</th><th>Qty</th><th>Amount</th></tr>';
              foreach ($contents as $bid=>$qty)
              {
                $qry="select * from tbbook where bid in($bid)";
                $res=mysqli_query($link,$qry) or die('Query_Error');

                if($row= mysqli_fetch_row($res))
                {

                    $out[]='<tr>';
                    $out[]='<td>';
                    $out[]="<a href=bookcart.php?action=Delete>Delete</a>";
                    $out[]='</td>';
                    $out[]='<td>';
                    $out[]="$row[1] by $$row[2]";
                    $out[]='</td>';
                    $out[]='<td>';
                    $out[]="$row[3]";
                    $out[]='</td>';
                    $out[]='<td>';
                    $out[]="$row[4]";
                    $out[]='</td>';
                    $out[]='<td>';
                    $out[]="<input type=text name=qty$row[0] value=$qty placeholder=QTY/>";
                    $out[]='</td>';
                    $out[]='<td>';
                    $amt=$row[4]*$qty;
                    $out[]=$amt;
                    $out[]='</td>';
                   $totalamt+=$amt;

                    $out[]='</tr>';
                }
              }
              $out[]='<tr>';
              $out[]='<td>';
                $out[]="Totalamt:$totalamt";
                $out[]='</td>';
                $out[]='<td>';
                $out[]="<a href='index.php'>Go Back</a>";
                $out[]='</td>';
                $out[]='</tr>';
                $_SESSION["totalamt"]=$totalamt;
                $out[]='</table>';
                $out[]="<input type=submit name=btnsubmit value=Update />";
                $out[]='</form>';

                $out[]="<a href=pay.php>Pay Now</a>";

                echo join($out);

            }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

After running this, I was not able to store the cart in this session. I am able to store the cart when navigating via the browser back button, but not via the anchor tag.

Comment: IT IS MAKING NEW ARRAY RATHER THAN STORING IN CURRENT ARRAY.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `session_start()` inside the index.php file?

Comment: there is no need to because the session is already started in this code... I am making 3 tier like logic will be in one file and presentation in another. Then I am calling this class by making an object. but i tried once it is giving error 'session is alredy started'

Comment: by the way this is shopping cart-> When i am adding the book in cart it is adding and able to store in session, i can check this by going back with the help of browser button . But when i add an anchor tag to redirect to homepage and new books but here the session is being lost or it is making new session,array also it is not adding in old one. Hope you understand the problem,if you not then ask me   .